# WPF loading indicator when Entity Framework loads data

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, busyindicator

When loading data from database with Entity Framework takes a long time I would like to show "loading" indicator on UI (WPF). For the indicator itself, I am using [WPF Loading Wait Adorner](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/57984/WPF-Loading-Wait-Adorner) as shown in the article.

The indicator works fine but is not showing when Entity Framework loads data. In that case the indicator won't show at all on UI.

I run this:

```
'show Adorner (loading indicator)
LoadingAdorner.IsAdornerVisible = Not LoadingAdorner.IsAdornerVisible

'read data from database with Entity Framework
Persons = _context.persons

'hide Adorner (loading indicator) after loading data is completed
LoadingAdorner.IsAdornerVisible = Not LoadingAdorner.IsAdornerVisible
```

and

```
<ac:AdornedControl Name="LoadingAdorner">
        <ac:AdornedControl.AdornerContent>
            <local:LoadingWait></local:LoadingWait>
        </ac:AdornedControl.AdornerContent>
        <ListBox>
            ...code not shown
        </ListBox>  
</ac:AdornedControl>
```

Only after the data is loaded, the indicator becomes visible.
What am I missing and how to show the indicator WHILE the data is loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that you're running your EF call in Main thread. This blocks UI from being updated until you'll receive all data from the DB. 
To fix this just add `BackgroundWorker` or async methods:

```
  var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
  worker.DoWork += (s, e) => {
       this.IsLoading = true;
       this.Persons = _context.persons;
    };        
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) => {
       this.IsLoading = false;
    };
```

**Important**: Keep in mind cross-thread access (**DoWork** performed in background thread, **Completed** - UI thread )

And at the end to start/trigger **DoWork** you will need to execute `.RunWorkerAsync()` on your worker.

Comment: how can I use it? How can I say to it "doWork" now?

Comment: @PieroAlberto `.RunWorkerAsync();` will start work.